# Creating ActiveRecord Associations on Existing Columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, rails-activerecord

I have two models: `User` and `Listing`.
I am trying to set up a one-to-many relationship between them via existing db columns.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :listings

class Listing < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :user, foreign_key: "user_id"
```

This is my migration:

```
class AddFkToListing < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    add_foreign_key :listings, :users, column: :user_id, primary_key: :user_id
  end
end
```

But it created the foreign key in table `users` on column `id`.
Any idea how to do this properly?

Here is the DB schema:

```
  create_table "listings", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "listing_id"
    t.string "state"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.string "title"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["listing_id"], name: "index_listings_on_listing_id", unique: true
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "email"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "password_digest"
    t.string "remember_digest"
    t.boolean "admin", default: false
    t.string "activation_digest"
    t.boolean "activated", default: false
    t.datetime "activated_at"
    t.string "reset_digest"
    t.datetime "reset_sent_at"
    t.string "request_token"
    t.string "request_secret"
    t.string "oauth_verifier"
    t.string "oauth_token"
    t.string "login_name"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  end
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: It should have added a field `user_id` in the `listings` table that references the `id` column of table `users` --so the foreign key references the id column of users, which sounds correct? It could be simpler, but your code looks correct to me (no need to specify the foreign key for instance in the belongs_to).

Comment: There is no need to specify  foreign_key: "user_id" in association in Listing class.

Comment: Thank you so much. The Listing.user_id column is conventional but the User.user_id is unconventional. Right now it ties it to User.id. I have updated the DB schema in the original post. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a conventional foreign key field name (`user_id` in `listings` table), I believe this should work just fine for you:

```
class AddFkToListing < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    add_foreign_key :listings, :users
  end
end
```

The syntax of `add_foreign_key` is:

- first argument (`:listings`) - table which should contain foreign key
- second argument (`:users`) - table which should be used for constraint
- `column: :user_id` - specifies to which field of the `listings` table constraint should be applied
- `primary_key:` - specifies the field of the `users` table to build a constraint

(see https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/add_foreign_key)

The `primary_key: :user_id` part in your example actually refers (tries to) to non-existing `user_id` field in `users` table.

Comment: Thank you so much. The Listing.user_id column is conventional but the User.user_id is unconventional. Right now it ties it to User.id. I have updated the DB schema in the original post. Any idea?